# Capybara issue when trying to click form submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm pretty new to Ruby/Rails and especially to Capybara and the whole process, so please bear with me as I've spent a lot of time on this already and I finally decided to ask because I'm sure it's something simple that I just am as-of-yet unaware of.

So I have a form that has several checkboxes that are designed to filter the results displayed (ie, you select one or more and submit and thew page reloads with the list filtered).  In my features file, I have the following scenarios (the button to submit the form has a value="Refresh"):

```
Scenario: no ratings selected
  When I uncheck the following ratings: G, PG, PG-13, NC-17, R
  And I press "Refresh"
  Then show me the page
  And I should see none of the movies

Scenario: all ratings selected
  When I check the following ratings: G, PG, PG-13, NC-17, R
  And I press "Refresh"
  Then show me the page
  And I should see all of the movies
```

When I run this with rake features, it gives the following output:

```
    And I press "Refresh"                                        #     features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:61
xprop:  unable to open display ''
```

I am using page.body a little later in the scenario and I believe this is the reason I then get the following errors:

```
Deprecated: please use #source_tags instead.
Warning: program returned non-zero exit code #1
WARNING: You don't seem to have any mimeinfo.cache files.
Try running the update-desktop-database command. If you
don't have this command you should install the
desktop-file-utils package. This package is available from
<link>
No applications found for mimetype: text/html
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 563: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 563: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 563: lynx: not found
Error occured while reset 800b: errno=5
xdg-open: no method available for opening '/home/ubuntu/hw3_rottenpotatoes/tmp/capybara    /capybara-201203260037535403047955.html'
Error occured: errno=5
Warning: program returned non-zero exit code #1
WARNING: You don't seem to have any mimeinfo.cache files.
Try running the update-desktop-database command. If you
don't have this command you should install the
desktop-file-utils package. This package is available from
<link>
No applications found for mimetype: text/html
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 563: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 563: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 563: lynx: not found
Error occured while reset 800b: errno=5
xdg-open: no method available for opening '/home/ubuntu/hw3_rottenpotatoes/tmp/capybara    /capybara-201203260037534847572739.html'
Error occured: errno=5
Warning: program returned non-zero exit code #1
WARNING: You don't seem to have any mimeinfo.cache files.
Try running the update-desktop-database command. If you
don't have this command you should install the
desktop-file-utils package. This package is available from
<link>
No applications found for mimetype: text/html
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 563: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 563: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 563: lynx: not found
Error occured while reset 800b: errno=5
xdg-open: no method available for opening '/home/ubuntu/hw3_rottenpotatoes/tmp/capybara    /capybara-20120326003754980186501.html'
```

Here are the relevant step definitions

```
When /I (un)?check the following ratings: (.*)/ do |unc, rating_list|
  rating_list.split(", ").each do |r|
    if(unc)
      uncheck("ratings_#{r}")
    else
      check("ratings_#{r}")
    end
  end
  assert true, "Implemented checking function"
end


Then /I should (not )?see movies with the following ratings: (.*)/ do |nt, rating_list|
  flag = true
  rating_list.split(", ").each do |r|
    if(nt)
      if(page.body =~ /<td>#{r}/)
        flag = false;
      end
    else
      if(page.body !~ /<td>#{r}/)
        flag = false
      end
    end
  end
  assert flag, "Seeing (or not) movies of ratings list - implemented"
end


Then /I should see all of the movies/ do
  tot = Movie.all.count
  assert page.have_selector('tbody tr', :count => tot)
end


Then /I should see none of the movies/ do
  num = page.body.scan(/00:00:00 UTC/m).length
  assert size == 0, "Showing no movies - implemented"
end



When /^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"$/ do |button|
  click_button(button)
end

Then /^show me the page$/ do
  save_and_open_page
end
```

I have been researching for days when I have time and there is just so much I don't know.  Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the steps definitions?

Comment: Sure, I added the relevant ones.

Comment: I'd say it's more an environment / platform issue. Than the way your steps are written. Can you run any other tests? Have you checked the desktop-file-utils package that's mentioned in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't have any browser installed to handle html files.
It seems you are using an headless server (without X) so your system is trying to find a suitable browser (one that can be run from the command line).

Take a look at [Capybara drivers](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers) and choose an appropriate one.